# Is it possible to pull and inspect the database file of contacts in android

Tags: android

I am using android Pie, tring to understand contentprovider in the context of contacts table, it is a bit confusing so I am trying to figure out how to pull the contacts database file from android's storage, so that I can inspect the structure and contents of the table.
Please advise. did some research and it is apparently supposed to be here

```
   /data /data /com.android.providers.contacts /databases /contacts2.db
```

Using android studio when I browse this location it does not show any contents please advise

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible, although you may need a device that allows root access. The path you posted looks correct, but you connect to your device via ADB and search for it on the device:

```
$ adb root
$ adb remount
$ adb shell
$ find . -name "contacts2.db"
```

Copy the path, and then exit out of adb and use:

```
$ adb pull <path>
```

You will then be able to access the file with a SQL database browser.

Comment: First step happens but its silent, at second step I get the message, not running as root, try "adb root"  first

Comment: Ensure you've enabled *Developer Options* in your phone settings and try again